How should I parse Vec<Row> from postgres crate into a Vec<String> in Rust?
I am building a tauri app, where some SQL query will come from the frontend and the rust backend has to execute that query.
I am using postgres crate for handling database queries.
Running a query returns a Vec<Row> but I can not return Vec<Row> from my tauri command, so I tried to  convert it to a Vec<String>. The issue here is backend does not know how many column values will be in the result as the query is unknown beforehand.
This was my first try but this does not work due to obvious type conversion errors.
#[tauri::command]
fn run_query(query: String) -> Result<Vec<String>, String> {
    let mut conn = database_util::get_db_connection();
    let result = match conn.query(query.as_str(), &[]) {
        Ok(res) => {
            let mut rows = Vec::new();
            for row in res {
                let mut row_str = String::new();
                for i in 0..row.len() {
                    let value: Option<String> = row.get(i);
                    row_str.push_str(&format!("{:?} ", value));
                }
                rows.push(row_str);
            }
            Ok(rows)
        },
        Err(err) => {
            Err(err.to_string())
        }
    };

    result
}

Finally I wrote something like this but still the issue of how many column remains.
#[tauri::command]
fn run_query(query: String) -> Result<Vec<String>, String> {
    let mut conn = database_util::get_db_connection();
    let result = match conn.query(query.as_str(), &[]) {
        Ok(res) => {
            let mut rows = Vec::new();
            for row in res {
                let mut row_str = String::new();
                let field_one: i32 = row.get(0);
                let field_two: Option<&str> = row.get(1);
                let field_three: Option<&str> = row.get(2);
                // ... there could be more fields depending on the query passed 
                row_str.push_str(&format!("{} {:?} {:?}", field_one, field_two, field_three));
                rows.push(row_str);
            }
            Ok(rows)
        },
        Err(err) => {
            Err(err.to_string())
        }
    };

    result
}

I am coming from JS background so I am still new to rust world, so if there is another way to tackle this then please tell me how.
I tried googling, reading the documentation of the postgres crate but nothing worked.
I am expecting to send the result of the query to the frontend.

What are the Postgres types of the columns?

This is the db schema.

create table users(
 user_id serial primary key,
 name varchar,
 user_name varchar(255) not null unique,
 email varchar not null unique,
 is_admin bool not null,
 profile_photo varchar,
 hashed_password varchar not null,
 bio varchar,
 account_type account_type not null default 'basic',
 created_at timestamp default current_timestamp
);


And, to be clear, the query is for all of the table's columns in order?

Query can be for all of the columns or some of the columns. eg select user_name, email from users; or select * from users;

Why not define a serializable struct that has optional fields for each of the columns? Then serialize it to JSON or whatever and sent it to the frontend.

I am new to rust. Can you show me the code of the serializable struct or the approach you are suggesting?

Why not use an ORM like diesel? Doing it your way means a loot of boring repetitive code mapping sql data to structs.

I haven't done any development with Tauri personally, but according their guide you should be able to just implement the traits serde::Deserialize and serde::Serialize for Vec<Row> and return Vec<Row> like usual. Although, I think it would be more practical to map the Row result to some custom struct, and then just derive serde::Serialize and serde::Deserialize for its type. If you're dealing with different types of results, you could make the result type generic for the function, or wrap the result type in an enum type.

An independent crate can't implement Deserialize/Serialize for Vec<Row> due to the orphan rule.

It looks like the with-serde_json-1 feature lets you deserialize a Row into a serde_json::Value, so you don't have to implement anything additional, as long as you implement Deserialize for your own type to get an instance of it from a serde_json::Value.

@BallpointBen Event better!
